# How to have emotional range whilst maintaining a consistent tone/mood/atmosphere?

Tags: style, tone, atmosphere

I know that a good way of enriching your writing is to include a range of emotions, obviously following a flow, and making sure it makes sense overall, not just cycling through them just to check them off a list. But another important thing is to have a consistent and cohesive tone/mood/atmosphere. (I'm not sure what specifically would be the best word here, but one of them.)

The overall feel I'm going for is quiet, introspective and almost bittersweet. How can I make sure my writing is consistent without feeling too same-y?

Comment: Maybe you could consider the overall tone as a baseline that things return to. So you could have highs and lows, outburst of humor or anger, but always returning back to the bittersweet baseline.

Comment: tone is fixed in the 2nd and 3rd draft rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

You want the mood to color the story and set the tonality.  Comic relief in tragedy and tragic relief in comedy are swings within the scope of the mood.  *Hamlet* has the prince  hearing the jests of a gravedigger about the staying powers of corpses, for instance.  *As You Like It* has Orlando gravely wounded saving his brother but offstage and recovering swiftly.